# Change colours in visreg2D regression plot

Tags: r, regression, interaction

A great way to visualise the results of a regression in R is the `visreg` package. I particularly like the plots that show an interaction with different shades of two colours:

```
library(visreg)
fit.heat <- lm(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp, data = airquality)
visreg2d(fit.heat, "Wind", "Temp", plot.type = "image")
```

(from the [`visreg` documentation](http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/publications/visreg.pdf))

The two colours used are red and blue.

**Question**

How can I change the colors? Shades of red and blue don't look too well in black and white print, red and blue can't be distinguished. I would be happy with a scale from blue to white for example. Any chances this can be done?

Comment: I think your library is called visreg and not airquality, please check

Comment: Sorry for that, I corrected the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color of the graph by adding a colour argument inside visreg2d function. You can for example use one of the standard R palettes such as `terrain.colors()` or `heat.colors()`or modify/create your own palettes e.g. with the package RColorBrewer (as in the example attached).

```
visreg2d(model, x="RELATEDNESS", y = "Hs_obs", scale = "response", 
xlab = "Relatedness", ylab = "Heterozygosity", main = "Flower abundance", 
zlim = c(0,100), col = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Reds"))(20))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you type in

```
edit(visreg2d)
```

you will be able to view the color pallet for this function. You can edit here and choose a color combination of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm using RStudio and when I press 'Save' the changes won't get saved. Am I doing something wrong? I couldn't find anything on this being an issue with RStudio. I also tried just copying the function and code and setting up my own new function. But this produces error messages I can't intepret.

Comment: It just has 'save' and 'cancel'.

Comment: You could try customizing RStudio - check out this http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/using/customizing

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure any of these options will add a 'save as' button. I guess I'll have to try it in plain R.