# regarding making the visreg plot to be colorful

Tags: r, regression

I used `visreg` to generate the surface plot,

```
testmodel<-lm(y~t1+t2+t3+t4+t5+t6+t7+t1:t7+t2:t3+t5:t6,data=df)
visreg2d(testmodel,"t7","t2",plot.type="persp")
```

The generated plot is shown as a black-and-white plot. How can make it to be colorful.

[image]

Comment: may be this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933064/change-colours-in-visreg2d-regression-plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the fill color for the surface with the `col` parameter and the color for the gridlines with the `border` parameter. See the help for the `persp` function for additional options (`visreg2d` uses the `persp` function to draw the plot if you set `plot.type="persp"`).

```
library(visreg)
testmodel <- lm(mpg ~ cyl*wt + gear + carb, data=mtcars)

# red fill, yellow gridlines
visreg2d(testmodel,"cyl","wt",plot.type="persp", 
         col="red", border="yellow",
         theta=120, phi=10, r=10)

# Multicolor fill, yellow gridlines
visreg2d(testmodel,"cyl","wt",plot.type="persp", 
         col=c("red","green","blue","violet"), border="yellow",
         theta=120, phi=10, r=10)
```

And here's the result:

[image]